# How can I remove StaxEventItemWriter <root> tag added by start/end Document methods?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, spring-batch

How can I remove StaxEventItemWriter   tag added by start/end Document methods ?

It is added by default when I'm generating the XML file, So please can any one tell me how I can remove default root tag.

```
 Ex-
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <root>
    <ressourcespleiade date="2015-10-03 06:38:00.000">
    ---
    ---
    </..>
```

Comment: If you remove that tag, it's not a valid XML document...

Comment: I want <ressourcespleiade> tag as a root only.

Comment: Good question. I'm currently wondering how to achieve this, having the written item being the root

Answer (score 3):

I ended doing something like this:

```
/**
 * {@link StaxEventItemWriter} which write no root tag as written elements are root
 * @param <T> Type of the written elements
 *
 * @author francois.dupire
 */
public class NoRootStaxEventItemWriter<T> extends StaxEventItemWriter<T> {

    /*
     * Methods
     */
    @Override
    protected void startDocument(XMLEventWriter writer) throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLEventFactory factory = createXmlEventFactory();

        // write start document
        writer.add(factory.createStartDocument(getEncoding(), getVersion()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void endDocument(XMLEventWriter writer) { }

}
```

IMO, that's not really clean, but not really bad either. That way you can rely on every mecanism of the StaxEventItemWriter class but writing no root element.