# Spring batch, how to remove root tag

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a problem with processing file.I my case i need to edit the same file while i read, unfortunetly StaxEventItemWriter adding new root element but in file i have one. My input XML file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <info>
 <header>
  ...
 </header>
  <files>
    <file>
     </file>
  </files>
  <status>
  </status>
  </info>
```

but my output file have additional root tag

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<info>
<header>
 ...
</header>
<files>
    <file>
    </file>
</files>
<status>
</status>
</info>
</info>
```

And here is my question, how i could remove the additional tag?
My java classes:
**RootElement.class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "info")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RootElement {
@XmlElement(name = "header")
private Header header;
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name = "file")
private List<File> files;
@XmlElement(name="status")
private Status status;
//Geters and setters
```

**Header.class**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Header {

@XmlElement(name = "main_doc_id")
private String mainDocId;

@XmlElement(name = "doc_id")
private String docId;
@XmlElement(name = "creation_time")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime creationDate;
@XmlElement(name = "type")
private String type;`
```

**Satus.class**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Status {
@XmlElement(name = "code")
private Integer code;
@XmlElement(name = "message")
private String message;
@XmlElement(name = "start_time")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime localTime;
@XmlElement(name = "end_time")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime endTime;
```

**File.class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "file")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class File {
@XmlElement(name = "name")
private String name;
@XmlElement(name = "checksum")
private String checkSum;
@XmlElement(name = "type")
private String type;
@XmlElement(name = "status")
private Status status;
```

And my **ItemWriter class**

```
 public class FileWriter  implements ItemWriter<RootElement> {
@Override
public void write(List<? extends RootElement> list) throws IOException {
   StaxEventItemWriter<RootElement> writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
    try {
        writer.setResource(new UrlResource(getProcessingFileName()));
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        writer.setRootTagName("info");
        writer.setOverwriteOutput(true);
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(RootElement.class);
        writer.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
    writer.open(executionContext);
    writer.write(list);
    writer.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
writer.setRootTagName("info");
```

Since you already use `@XmlRootElement(name = "info")` in `RootElement.class`. 
Using both places create `<info>` tag 2 times.

Comment: When i removed the line StaxEventWriter added <root> tag

Comment: You can use custom implementation extending StaxEventWriter, here you find an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110971/how-can-i-remove-staxeventitemwriter-root-tag-added-by-start-end-document-meth

Answer (score 0):

The `write` method of an `ItemWriter` is called for every chunk. In your code, you are creating a `StaxEventItemWriter` in this method and opening/closing this writer. So for each chunk, you will have a new writer opening/closing the file and overriding it.

I encourage you to first take some time to understand the [chunk oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) and take a look at the [code samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) to see how to correctly configure batch components.